# Place avatar as listing cover using filter

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, avatar

I am using a wordpress theme that has many listings. Each of these listings has a cover image. This cover image is used as the default image for that listing whenever you search. There are two types of search results that the user can switch between "list" & "Grid".

I have already replaced the cover image with the avatar in the list search by placing "**echo get_wp_user_avatar( $user_id, 'thumbnail', 210 );**" under the div with the class *"job_listing-entry-thumbnail"*, but the default image for the "Grid" is being placed by the code in the header  **"echo apply_filters( 'listify_cover', 'job_listing-entry-header listing-cover' );**"

I am trying to make the users avatar come up as the default image in the search grid and I have attempted filtering it and placing the code there, but it has not worked.

Any help is appreciated.

```
<li id="job_listing-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php job_listing_class(); ?> <?php 
echo apply_filters('listify_job_listing_data', '', false ); ?>>

<div class="content-box">
    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="job_listing-clickbox"></a> 

    <header <?php echo apply_filters( 'listify_cover', 'job_listing-entry-header listing-cover' ); ?>>
        <?php do_action( 'listify_content_job_listing_header_before' ); ?>

        <div class="job_listing-entry-header-wrapper cover-wrapper">

            <div class="job_listing-entry-thumbnail">
                  <div class="job_listing-author-avatar1" >
            <?php echo get_wp_user_avatar( $user_id, 'thumbnail', 210 ); ?>
        </div>  
                <!-- <div <?php echo apply_filters( 'listify_cover', 'list-cover' ); ?>></div>  -->
            </div>
            <div class="job_listing-entry-meta">
                <?php do_action( 'listify_content_job_listing_meta' ); ?>

            </div>

        </div>
```

```
    </header><!-- .entry-header -->


    <footer class="job_listing-entry-footer">

        <?php do_action( 'listify_content_job_listing_footer' ); ?>

    </footer><!-- .entry-footer -->

    </div>
  </li><!-- #post-## -->
```

Comment: How are you setting `$user_id`?

Comment: The results are in a loop, for each listing, and each listing has an author which is what $user_id is using.